# Modifying a WSDL file manually

Tags: soap, wsdl, soapui

I have a URL to see the wsdl file. But I have to make some changes to it and again test it.
How can I do it.
I am using Soap UI to view the XML content.

Comment: A WSDL is an artefact deployed to your container with the other build artefacts. Pretty sure you cannot modify it from the client side.

Comment: @ou_ryperd I want to make changes to the code which generates the wsdl.  Not from the client side.